# Why is the front part of the engine not painted?

Tags: engine, paint

The engines are always painted a certain colour but the front part is always grey.

[Source](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:737_CFM56_engine.jpg)

[image: cfm56]

And here on the XWB:
[image: xwb]

[Source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolls-Royce_Trent_XWB#/media/File%3ATrent_XWB_(14272089101)_(2).jpg)

Why is it that?

Comment: Not directly related to your question but what's the red line on the side of both engines that sort of goes halfway around?

Comment: Red line is to indicate danger area. No personnel allowed in front of red line when engine is running. http://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/articles/qtr_3_08/article_04_3.html

Comment: The "no people" symbol suggests that the red line indicates how far back from the inlet you should remain for safety.

Comment: @curious_cat if you are standing forward of that line and the engine is spooled, you are going on a fatal trip through the N1 fan.

Comment: @casey like [This](https://youtu.be/Q0nRt9g6tdg)?

Comment: @TomMcW that guy got lucky. I know some flight attendants that watched a mx tech turn into a pile of goo and chunks no heavier than 2 lbs during a static runup on a 737.

Comment: @casey Ouch! Yes, that guy got super lucky. Whoever manufactured that helmet he was wearing should be commended. It had to have busted every compressor blade for him to have survived that. 12 stages in the J52 on the A6

Comment: @TomMcW According to the narration, a strap on his suit snagged on a probe and held him in position a few inches in front of the fan. The engines themselves are several feet aft of the front of the intake.

Comment: @reirab  Ah. I didn't watch the whole thing. I've seen that video a thousand times. It's so freakish you can't stop watching. But I wouldn't want to see what the flight attendants saw that Casey mentioned. I guess the comp blades must be pretty far back from the inlet. He wouldn't get so lucky on a high bypass engine. The fan is right there. Like a giant Cuisinart!

Comment: @vasin1987 - I especially like how that article is entitled "Preventing engine ingestion *injuries*...." as if "being turned into mince" still falls under the "injury" banner

Comment: @casey - Preposterous! [What's the worst that could happen?](http://imgur.com/a/mbsr5)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The engine inlet lip is bare metal to facilitate anti-icing. The area is heated from within using hot engine bleed air.

This partial schematic (from Boeing [AERO QTR_01.12](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/articles/2012_q1/)) shows the engine anti-ice valve, which controls the air supply to the inlet lip:
[image: 747-8 Engine Bleed Schematic]

Interesting side note: Even the 787 "no-bleed" system architecture uses bleed air for engine anti-ice.

Answer (score 6):

There are two reasons I can think of for this:

1. Aerodynamic reasons. Believe it or not, even paint can change the dynamics of a plane, to the point that Boeing discourages  multi-colored paint jobs or liveries on 787 nacelle, claiming they affect performance.
2. If that part of the engine were painted, there would be risk of paint chips being sucked into the engines, potentially damaging them. While this may seem far-fetched, [this](http://www.aviationpros.com/article/10374800/engine-forensics) account shows that even paint chips can pose a foreign object debris threat to an engine. By not painting this part of the nacelle, the risk of paint flecking off and into the engine is reduced.

Comment: The linked article is about chips of concrete and runway marking paint causing damage. The stuff they use to paint the runway markings is _much_ more substantial than the paint used on planes.

Comment: what is the second reason ?