# Why are the leading edges of the 787's horizontal and vertical stabilizers not painted?

Tags: aircraft-design, anti-ice, paint

The other day I made a [question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25013/why-is-the-front-part-of-the-engine-not-painted) about the engine painting and why it isn't painted at the front part. The answer was: to facilitate anti-ice system. 
[image: 787]
Source: [fervegeon.com](http://fevergeon.com/aerospace/)

So perhaps the leading edge of the horizontal and vertical stabilizer have a sort of anti-ice system?

And this is not only on the 787; the 777 also has the leading edges unpainted.
[image: 777] 
[Source](http://training.deicinginnovations.com/?p=2565)

And on the 757 and winglet.
[image]
Source: [flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/sfphotocraft/15275093479)

Comment: Yes, it uses a heated edge system designed to melt the boundary layer of ice on leading edge surfaces. The system is designed by [GKN](http://www.gkn.com/aerospace/products-and-capabilities/ice-protection/Pages/default.aspx).

Comment: @JanHudec perhaps there is an option to paint them, with a reduction in icing allowances.

Comment: @JanHudec Not all aircraft have heated horizontal or vertical stabilizers (for instance, the Learjets only have the horizontal stabilizer heated (electrically), and the Falcons don't heat either one at all).

Comment: @JanHudec As I'm sure you know, many aircraft have no anti-icing systems at all, or have only pitot probe heat. I don't think you meant to include these types in your statement, but I just wanted to make sure that is clear to others.

Comment: On this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_NjnaUKcIk (minute 16:23-16:55) a man is putting a tube on the leading edge of the wing and then covers it with a bare metal. Perhaps the same happens on the leading edge of horizontal and vetical stabilizers.

Comment: The 787 **does not** have heated empennage leading edges. The anti-ice is only on some of the _wing slats_. This 787-9 has the [Hybrid Laminar Flow Control](https://www.flightglobal.com/news/articles/farnborough-aero-secrets-of-boeings-new-dreamliner-401784/) system integrated into the tailplane leading edges.

Comment: I always assumed a lot of leading edges were left unpainted on all kinds of aircraft because of the paint frequently wearing off in those places. Better to leave it neatly unpainted than to have unsightly chips that have to be frequently touched up.

Comment: Looks like I might be on to something but not quite right. "Leading edge erosion" is a problem. One solution appears to be applying erosion resistant films to leading edges. I wouldn't be surprised if the films have to be replaced from time to time, and that application and removal of the films might be best done on bare metal rather than painted metal. [3M's page on leading edge films](http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_EU/AerospaceSolutions/Home/Applications/RainAndSand/)

Comment: Another possibility is that leading edges have to be periodically replaced, and it's cheaper to keep the polished aluminum look rather than have custom colors applied for what is essentially a consumable part. Frankly, I suspect erosion is a likely factor in the answer to your question about engine fairings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aircraft stabilizers (both vertical and horizontal) usually have metallic leading edges without paint or anti-erosion paint system. This can be seen in the following figure for Airbus A320 family.

[image: paint]

Image from [Airbus Structure Training Manual](http://lms.aeroflot.ru/data/Part145/Structure_Reapair/Paint%20system.pdf)

For aircraft with composite stabilizers, leading edge erosion is arrested by bonding metal to the leading edge, or making the [leading edge using metal, as in 787](http://old.seattletimes.com/html/boeingaerospace/2003612251_boeing111.html):

> The .. leading edge assembly, ..., with an aluminum edge and a fiberglass and paper-honeycomb skin.

In such cases, (as @Todd points out), the leading edge is usually left unpainted in order to prevent paint erosion. This method is used in the leading edge of the main rotor blades of a number of helicopters. In such cases, either the bare metal is left as is or a protective film is used to combat erosion.